# how do you implement allocating strategy with c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have two workers.If I have configured a strategy that 60% tasks are allocate to A worker and the rest to B worker.

how do you implement with c++.

what is your suggestion?

```
map<string,float> m_percent;
m_percent.insert(make_pair("countA",0.6));
m_percent.insert(make_pair("countB",0.1));
m_percent.insert(make_pair("countC",0.3));

map<string,int> m_count;

m_count.insert(make_pair("total",0));

map<string,int>::iterator it = m_count.find("countA");
map<string,int>::iterator itc =m_count.find("total");
map<string,float>::iterator itp=m_percent.find("countA");
if(it== m_count.end())//use countA
{      

    m_count.insert(make_pair("countA",1));

 }     
else
{
    int &c = it->second; 
    if(itc!=m_count.end()&&itp!=m_percent.end())
    {
        float f=(c+1)*100/(itc->second+1)*100.0
        if (f<=itp->second)
        {
            it->second=it->second+1;


        }   
    }
}   


if(itc!=m_count.end())
{
   itc->second=itc->second+1;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about number of tasks with no regard to complexity, simply keep a count of how many jobs have been allocated to each. Let's call these counts `countA` for the jobs allocated to `A`, and `count` for the total number of jobs (for simplicity in calculations), and initialise them to zero.

Then, when a job comes in, allocate as per the following:

- if `count` is equal to zero, allocate it to `A` and increment both `countA` and `count`.
- otherwise, if `countA / count` is less than `0.6`, allocate it to `A` and increment both `countA` and `count`.
- otherwise allocate it to `B` and just increment `count`.

This will, over the long term, tend to average out allocations so that `A` gets 60%:

```
countA  count  countA/count  allocateTo
------  -----  ------------  ----------
     0      0             ?      A
     1      1         1.000      B
     1      2         0.500      A
     2      3         0.667      B
     2      4         0.500      A
     3      5         0.600      B
     3      6         0.500      A
     4      7         0.571      A
     5      8         0.625      B
     5      9         0.556      A
     6     10         0.600      B
     6     11         0.545      A
     7     12         0.583      A
     8     13         0.615      B
     8     14         0.571      A
     9     15         0.600      B
     9     16         0.563      A
    10     17         0.588      A
    11     18         0.611      B
    11     19         0.579      A
    12     20         0.600
```

... and so on.